# Ocean modifier foam spray?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, ocean-simulation

Is there a way to make the ocean modifier fake foam spray? I already displace the water with dynamic paint, but I still am stumped as to how to create the foam. I'm assuming it's a particle system of some sort, but I'm not where to place the emitter or what general settings to change (I just need some general tips).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what question you're asking, you've mentioned collisions in the question title but seem to be mainly asking how to create boat spray?

Comment: Good point. I wrote half of the question before I figured out how to use dynamic paint, and needed help on just the boat spray. Updated.

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Foam or spray? You mentioned dynamic paint, so I'm guessing you want to know how to spawn collision particles?

Answer (score 11):

We need dynamic particle emission to do real foam spray. The foam mask in the Ocean Sim modifier was created to be ready once Blender caught up with that feature.

Once Lukas's Particle Nodes project is finished, it should allow for us to do that. http://phonybone.planetblender.org

The foam mask would be the source of the dynamic particle generation. The nice thing about the ocean mesh generated is that there are speed vectors associated with the waves, which I believe should also be able to be sampled and applied to the dynamic particles' starting velocities. Fingers crossed!

Comment: I should also clarify that I'm referring to foam/spray emitted from the peaks of the waves and not object/water interaction.

Comment: do you know the progress of these  features? if you are aware how to do this,  I could post a question if you could answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a dynamic paint modifier in weight paint mode that makes a vertex group around the object colliding with the ocean, which you could use as an emission vertex group for some particle systems.

Here is a [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/22736) with an example setup.
(Note, only worked for me with the 2.68RC)

However there [seems to be a bug](https://projects.blender.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=36108&group_id=9&atid=498) where the particles keep emitting
from the same spot.

> This is a limitation of the particle system
>   implementation unfortunately.
>   http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Development/Todo/Tools#Particles
>
> The location of emitted particles are determined in advance now and
>   stay fixed, so this can't be animated. There's been some working on
>   designing an improved particle system that can handle such animations
>   but it's not finished:
>   http://code.blender.org/index.php/2011/03/paged-buffers-for-particles/